# Is there any difference in meaning between "look through the window" and "look out of the window" and "look from the window"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *look through the window* and *look out of the window* and *look from the window*? For example:

> I often **look though the window** when it's raining.
>
> I often **look out of the window** when it's raining.
>
> I often **look from the window** when it's raining.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that "look through the window" could mean from the outside looking in.

> John stood outside the house, looking through the window at the people partying inside.

But in the context you give, the meaning is almost the same.  I wouldn't use "from the window" unless you were saying "Looking from a 10th-floor window", which is really about "from the 10th floor".

Comment: What about 'look out the window'? I saw this expression in some novel. Is this informal?

Comment: "look out the window" is a variant of "look out of the window"  same meaning @Michael

Comment: I know they have the same meaning. The point is, "look out the window" sounds a bit weird in grammar, so I'm unsure whether it is informal or not.

Comment: Just a variant.  It uses the prepostion "out" instead of "out of", no real grammar problem, not particularly informal or formal.  I don't see any particular need to change my answer.